# Can't show the whole string in a list using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

When you open the [sample project](https://github.com/ericcheungwork/SwiftUI-missing-text-problem-demo):

Press a row once first and a plus button will be appeared. After tap plus button once, a plus character will be appended to the row. If I tap the button for many times, the `++++` string will show `+...` (shown in the image below). I didn't expect this, I expect that the row height will be increased automatically so whole string can be shown. What should I do to fix it?

[image]

If I tap the plus button for 5-6 times, the row height will be increased automatically as expected.

[image]

#### Major project code in the [sample project](https://github.com/ericcheungwork/SwiftUI-missing-text-problem-demo):

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    
    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            List {
                ForEach(userData.subtasks) { subtask in
                    SubtaskRowNextToCard(subtaskModel: subtask)
                }
            }
            
            if userData.currentSubtask != nil {
                SubtaskCard()
                    .padding(.all)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
                        
            for _ in 0..<20 {
                appendASubtask()
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func appendASubtask() {
        let aSubtask = SubtaskModel(
        score: ""
        )
        
        userData.subtasks.append(aSubtask)
    }
    
}
```

SubtaskModel.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class SubtaskModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var score: String = ""
    
    init(
        score: String
    ) {
        self.score = score
    }
}
```

SubtaskRowNextToCard.swift

```
struct SubtaskRowNextToCard: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var subtaskModel: SubtaskModel
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    
    @State var scoreWithRound: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            userData.currentSubtask = subtaskModel
        }) {
            Text(scoreWithRound)
        }
        .onAppear {
            updateScore()
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name.init("changedCurrentSubtask"))) { obj in
            updateScore()
        }
        
    }
    
    func updateScore() {
        scoreWithRound = subtaskModel.score
    }
    
}
```

SubtaskCard.swift

```
struct SubtaskCard: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
        
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            print("+ button was tapped")
            appendScore(newScore: "+")
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        
    }
    
    func appendScore(newScore: String) {
        if let subtaskModel = userData.currentSubtask {
            subtaskModel.score = subtaskModel.score + newScore + " "
                        
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init("changedCurrentSubtask"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` and it wont truncate the text anymore:

```
  ForEach(userData.subtasks) { subtask in
                    SubtaskRowNextToCard(subtaskModel: subtask).fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                }
```

**EDIT**:
For the dynamic height fix:

Replace `Text` with `TextEditor` and you won't notice the flickering:

```
Text(scoreWithRound)
```

to

```
TextEditor(text: $scoreWithRound).allowsHitTesting(false)
```

Comment: It works but it didn't solve the problem perfectly. The height of row will be unexpected (less than the normal height) [See this example](https://github.com/ericcheungwork/SwiftUI-missing-text-problem-demo/blob/main/StackoverflowReplyingAnswer1/AnsReply1.PNG). After tap plus button for few time [the height becomes normal again](https://github.com/ericcheungwork/SwiftUI-missing-text-problem-demo/blob/main/StackoverflowReplyingAnswer1/AnsReply2.PNG)

Comment: Updated the answer, check if it works for you now.